# OpenSceneGraph: Transform "objects" from 3D model

Tags: c++, animation, graphics, transform, openscenegraph

I have an ac3d model file with objects grouped and named. How would I transform these specific objects (and not the whole model) using osg?

Is there a way I can create a node out of a object in the model to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer here: https://www.movesinstitute.org/Sullivan/OSGTutorials/osgDOF.html

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse your model graph and keep reference to your nodes of interest.

Here you have how to traverse an OSG graph: http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Support/Tutorials/FindingNodes

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up defining a findNamedNode function as mentioned in the link.